# Line spacing and indent in UITextView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, uitextview

Can anybody tell how to give line spacing and indent in UITextView. This question has been asked before but i am not getting the proper answer so i am asking again.

Thanks.

Comment: Explain it clearly that whats your actual requirement.

Comment: I want to add line space for the text in uitextview, and also have to apply indentation.